# How to add more then 1 database in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am trying to use more than 1 database in WordPress. do you have any solution. see below example code.

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
    define('DB_NAME', 'database');

    define('DB1_NAME', 'database1');
    define('DB2_NAME', 'database2');

/** MySQL database username */
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB1_USER', 'root');
    define('DB2_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
    define('DB1_PASSWORD', 'pass');
    define('DB2_PASSWORD', 'pass');

/** MySQL hostname */
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: What do you pretend to accomplish with 2 databases?

Comment: This is just setting up the names and credentials for the databases, its not actually doing anything. Where is the code you are using to connect? And where will you use the different databases?

Comment: @FluffyKitten database connection code is here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php

Comment: Please update the question with *your* database connection code. That is the default Wordpress database, but if you want to use other databases you need to connect to them yourself.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar I have more then 2K view per day on my website. but my database limit 7500 query in an hour.  I want to create more then 1 database to solve this issue.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I  want to connect more then 1 database with default wordpress database.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but just wondering why you choose to add a database as oppose to use a service that doesn't limit you to 7500 query? In fact, what are you using for the database?

Comment: @FluffyKitten https://mega.nz/#!pSIA0KAC!w2vvFWEjzkQqZc7nZhh0T-2tUjNef4uqV1uyKFyNs_M

Comment: @FluffyKitten download my program and try to use this, I think i miss config this program.

Comment: @MuhammadAsadNazeer There is only 1 default Wordpress database. If you want to connect to custom or external databases, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I known wordpress support by default 1 database. If your programer try to check my this program and suggest me were i am worng. mega.nz/#!pSIA0KAC!w2vvFWEjzkQqZc7nZhh0T-2tUjNef4uqV1uyKFyNs‌​_M

Comment: Please update your question with any additional information including the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should upgrade / migrate your hosting instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can always instantiate a new wpdb class to create a connection to a new database inside a function that requires it.

```
$my_db = new wpdb($dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname, $dbhost)
```